# LINQ: How To Bind to a list of Concatenated Strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, data-binding

I have this LINQ query in a method:

```
public List<String> GetListNameUsers() 
{
    using (var context = new UCDataContext()) 
    {
        return (from c in context.Users
                select (c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName) ).ToList();
    }
}
```

but this does not work. 
I want to return a string composed by FirstName + " " + LastName.

I am binding the result of this method to a `DropDownList`, as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="UsersODS"
     DataTextField="LastName" DataValueField="IDUser" />
```

The field LastName isn't recognized when my `DropDownList` is being databound.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Luigi

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "this does not work"? What exactly is the problem? Is this LINQ to SQL or what?

Comment: -1 Because from one of your comments the problem is actually with binding this query to a dropdown

Comment: Because give me this error (at runtime):

DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'LastName'. 
Description: An unhandled exception 

The problem, I think, is that my DropDownList has this property: 

DataTextField="LastName" 

Luigi

Answer (score 10):

```
public IList GetListNameUsers() 
{
    using (var context = new UCDataContext()) 
    {
        return (from c in context.Users
                select new { 
                     Name = c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName,
                     IDUser = c.IDUser
                   }
               ).ToList();
    }
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="UsersODS"
     DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="IDUser" />
```

Comment: This appears to be the most appropriate answer, can someone please mark it as such. What is key here is that he's selecting a complex object (as opposed to just a series of concatenated string values) which also contains a correlation ID that can be used for data binding purposes.

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the records (using ToList) then do the string concatenation in your client side

```
public List<String> GetListNameUsers()
{

 using (var context = new UCDataContext())
 {
     return context.Users
                   .Select(c=>new {c.LastName, c.FirstName})
                   .ToList()
                   .Select(c=>c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName)
                   .ToList();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your context provider is a database, which means that the LINQ expression has to be converted to an SQL-query. The SQL query generator may not support the conversion of string concatenation to proper SQL. Instead you could just convert the users to a plain old list and perform the select on that list instead.

Something like:

```
public List<String> GetListNameUsers()
{

 using (var context = new UCDataContext())
 {
     var users = (from c in context.Users.ToList()
             select (c.LastName + " " + c.FirstName) ).ToList();
 }

}
```